# SQLite, ASCII A-Z Check Constraint

Tags: sqlite, check-constraints, regular-expression, regex

I have the following table which I'm trying to limit the column "prefix" to ASCII alphabetical characters. However, I am still able to insert other characters after using the following constraint. Why is it not working?

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    prefix TEXT NOT NULL, 
    CHECK(prefix NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%')
)
```

Using Python's sqlite3 package and DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: There's a [sqlite extension repsositoriy](https://github.com/urbans0ft/sqlite-ext) which contains a `regexp` extension which should compile under Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 8):

The `LIKE` operator in SQL does *not* work like regular expressions. The pattern matches allowed by this operator are very simple, compared to the powerful regexp. Actually, you have two *metacharacters*: `%` means `(0 or more of anything)`, which would be the equivalent of a `.*` in a regexp, and `_` meaning `(1 of anything)`, which would be the equivalentof `.` in a regexp. And that's it.

This means your `CHECK` condition, as originally written, is not actually checking what you expect. The only thing it will complain about are statements like:

```
INSERT INTO test 
VALUES (37, 'hello [a-zA-Z] impossible');
```

that contain the literal `[a-zA-Z]`.

You can actually use a `REGEXP` operator and write:

```
CHECK (prefix REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]+$')
```

However, to be able to use it, you first need to install the [`sqlite3-pcre` pcre regex extension for sqlite3](https://github.com/ralight/sqlite3-pcre), on a Linux machine (there *may* be a Windows alternative, but I've not been able to find it). You can find more information and instructions at Stack Overflow's [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query).

---

Other databases such as PostgreSQL would let you use RegExp using the `~` operator. You can check it at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b071/1/0).

---

SQLite doc references and tutorials:

- [SQLite Like: Querying Data Based On Pattern Matching](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/)
- [The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, and MATCH operators](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)

Answer (score 3):

LIKE does not support character classes, but the (non-standard) [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) does:

```
CHECK (prefix NOT GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z]*')
```

Answer (score 2):

DB Browser for SQLite has support for the REGEX function (enabled by default) and you can add the function to your python project as the following

```
def regex(expr, item):
     reg = re.compile(expr)
     return reg.search(item) is not None

conn = sqlite3.connect(':MEMORY:')
conn.create_function("REGEXP", 2, regex)
```

Here is the (almost) equivalent check using GLOB

```
CHECK(prefix NOT GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z]*'))
```

The REGEX check will not allow an empty string, but this will, so if you care you can use

```
CHECK(length(prefix) > 0 AND prefix NOT GLOB '*[^a-zA-Z]*'))
```